# Authenticating Google sign in token id with the backend sever Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, authentication

My problem is that I don't understand how to authenticate my Signed In user's tokenId with my backend server. I am using mysql in backend and using volley to add the basic profile info of the user in my "user" table. My question is do i have to add a seperate column for token id and how to authenticate it. What changes i should make in my php script in order to authenticate the token id.

Answer (score 0):

Google sign in Api  return a GoogleSignInAccount object if sign in result success `GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();` , and this object has an ID field `acct.getId();`, you can treat this ID as the password in your backend server and authenticate users with it, every time user tries to login with google, check for his username and id if exists then this user already exists in your system, if not create a new user

Comment: What is the use of token id? And how can i use it? Do I need to store the token id in my table too?

Comment: I actually answered that, You can save the id in your table in the password field and treat it as user password and use it to authenticate users